# What are git methodologies for rapid deployment

Tags: git, version-control, methodology, release-management

I have a huge project without proper revision control system (I know it is bad and this is why I want to change).
What methodology should I use if I would like to make rapid weekly releases, and at the same time I want to have some side features that can take more than a month to implement.

The weekly releases will only contain some features but not all from all the features added (so out of 10 only 6 features would be added). I am very unsure what git commands to even use to pull out only certain features and leave the rest untouched.

Also if anyone can point to good git methodologies to use for different projects I will be very grateful. Additionally which git commands to use with said methodologies would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to get familiar with git overall. Don't worry though, your situation sounds pretty typical and Git is well-suited for this. You'll do a lot of branching and rebasing, so be sure you are comfortable with those concepts.

[This](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) page is a good high-level perspective on what is sounds like you are trying to accomplish. Good luck!

Comment: Also make sure you know which files should *not* be in your git repo - namely huge binary files that are subject to change. Compiled EXEs, DLLs, etc. are good candidates for exclusion - as long as they are rebuilt by your CI server at every build!

Comment: Thank you so much :) I searched everywhere and couldn't find anything this well written. this has all the ideologies and the commands!!! Thank you! :)